# Any horizontal collapsible splitter in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there any plugin or UI widget for splitter that can be collapsible which is open source. I can find similar here with jqwidgets?

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/index.htm#demos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm

But sadly, it is paid license.   Anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

See that one: http://methvin.com/splitter/